# On real roots of a polynomial in the form $ap(x)+bq(x)$

Tags: calculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, real-numbers

Assume $m\in \mathbb{N}$, $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, $a\neq 0$ and $(1+ix)^m=p(x)+iq(x)$.

> Can we conclude that all roots of the polynomial $ap(x)+bq(x)$ are real numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Set $x=\tan u$ then $p(x)+iq(x)=c(u)·(\cos (mu)+i\sin(mu))$ and 
$$
ap(x)+bq(x)=c(u)·r·\sin(mu+\phi)
$$
where $a=r\sinϕ$ and $b=r\cosϕ$. Thus the roots are determined as
$$
x_k=\tan u_k\text{ where } u_k=\frac{-\phi+\pi·k}m, \ k\in \Bbb Z,\text{ and } u_k\in(-\tfrac\pi2,\tfrac\pi2)
$$
Now you have to argue that there are $m$ different roots in this set.